# Insert nested json array into database

Tags: php

I am trying ti insert JSON array into my mysql database.Here I give format for that

```
array ${
    "customer_id": "1",
    "products":[ {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_qty": "2"
    }, {
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_qty": "4"
    }, {
        "product_id": "3",
        "product_qty": "12"
    }, {
        "product_id": "4",
        "product_qty": "22"
    }],
    "order_totalamount": "100"
}
```

I tried insert query as below:

```
foreach($data as $item) {

            //insert into mysql table
             $sql = "insert into `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,order_totalamount,order_id,order_date) values ($cus_id,$item[product_id],$item[product_qty],$order_totalamount,$cus_id,CURDATE())";
```

also decode JSON data, and foreach loop

Comment: What happens when you try?  Do you recieve an error message?  Is so what does it say?  Can you elaborate on *also decode JSON data, and foreach loop*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode` the string and iterate through the array of products and insert them one by one.

```
$data = json_decode($json_string);
$customer_id = $data->customer_id;

foreach($data->products as $product) // its a array of products you showed in json 
{
    // insert code here for mysql insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
$res = '{
"customer_id": "1",
"products":[ {
    "product_id": "1",
    "product_qty": "2"
}, {
    "product_id": "2",
    "product_qty": "4"
}, {
    "product_id": "3",
    "product_qty": "12"
}, {
    "product_id": "4",
    "product_qty": "22"
}],
"order_totalamount": "100"
}';

$data=json_decode($res);
foreach ($data->products as $item)
$sql = "insert into `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,order_totalamount,order_id,order_date    ) values ($data->customer_id,$item->product_id,$item->product_qty,$data->order_totalamount,$data->customer_id,CURDATE())";
```